# paypal buy it now button process flow

Tags: asp.net, redirect, paypal

Im adding paypal payments to my site via a buy it now button, which as i understand it posts a form to paypal then the user completes payment on paypal's site.

To process the order after payment is confirmed im using an IPN listener, but id like to do some processing on our server at the time of ordering too. Is it possible to have the buy it now button submit to our own server first so i can record the order, before redirecting to paypal for payment details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here.

First option that is more simple but can fail if the user did not have javascript, is to make a **post to your server with what data you like, with ajax**, and only after the return you let the user continue the submit.

Second option is to post your data to your server on code behind, there you prepare a simple page with auto submit to paypal - actually you make a **redirect with post**. Here you can find source code and one example on how to make it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have many options.

As you said, the buy now button is nothing more than a form post to PayPal.  You can build your own form using any of their [standard variables](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) rather than be limited to these buttons.  They call this the [cart upload method](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload).

With this method you can do whatever you need to do whatever local processing you need to do prior to ever sending the user over to PayPal.  It's a good practice to create an order record of some kind in your own system which you can then include with your PayPal payment info.  That same value will come back in IPN so you can process it post-payment as well.

Another option that would you open you up even more is to use the [Express Checkout APIs](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec).  This gives you complete control of your checkout system and has more features than standard payments.  I recommend this if you're familiar with web service APIs.

Of course, IPN works with Express Checkout, too, so you can still use that for whatever you want/need as well.

Comment: I understand I can build the form manually then have that form submit to my local server to create order record etc. The bit I'm still not clear on is how that same form then gets posted to paypal and user is sent there